# How do i get User email in posts view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my posts#index so far:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %><br>
    <%= post.body %> <br>
    <b>Author:</b> <%= post.user_id %>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to put user.email there instead of id. How can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [Rails docs for model associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Long story short, you should have a relationship between post and user (a users have many posts) and get the email like `post.user.email`